# Hard symbolic link directory

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I am taking over control of a server and I have found a directory in two different locations:

```
/var/www
/home/user.name (i.e., ~/)
```

that have the exact same inode number:

```
ls -i
11895253 directory.name
```

I had thought that hard links on directories were entirely impossible. What is this then? How does a folder exist in two places at once with the exact same contents?

Comment: Post here output of `mount`.

Comment: They are probably under different mount points, so they are not hard links, although they may end up referencing the same directory.

Comment: @Eddy_Em mount gave me: `/var/www/directory.name on /home/user.name/directory.name type none (rw,bind)`

Comment: And that's an answer to your question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a "bind mount". From the [`mount` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> The bind mounts.
>   Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else. The call is

```
 mount --bind olddir newdir
```

See also http://backdrift.org/how-to-use-bind-mounts-in-linux and http://backdrift.org/how-to-use-bind-mounts-in-linux.